# Removing grid from scanned image

Tags: python, opencv, handwriting

I have to recognize the text of the hand-filled bank form. The form has a grid as shown in the image. I am new to Image Processing. I read few papers on handwriting recognition and did denoising, binarization as preprocessing tasks. I want to segment the image now and recognize the characters using a Neural Network. To segment the characters I want to get rid of the grid.

Thank you very much in advance.
[image]

Comment: SO is not a coding site. Please show some work so that we can help you with making it better.

Comment: @DYZ I have tried using Denoising, Binarization and Edge detection on the image provided above. I am not understanding how to get rid of the grid. Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: try erosion and dilation operators

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a solution using OpenCV.

First, I inverted the image:

```
ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

[image]

Now I performed **morphological opening operation**:

```
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh2, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, k2)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
```

[image]

You can see that the grid lines have disappeared. But there are some gaos in some of the characters as well. So to fill the gaps I performed **morphological dilation operation**:

```
dilate = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, k1)
cv2.imshow('dilation', dilate)
```

[image]

You can check out [THIS LINK](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) for more **morphological operations** and **kernels** used.

Comment: @Soltius Hey any idea on how to get the characters back to normal as in the original image?

Comment: What does closing give instead of dilatation ?

Comment: @Soltius **Closing** is generally used to fill some holes/speckles/gaps **inside** a binary image. [SEE HERE](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#morphological-ops)

Comment: Sure that's the general way it's used but I think it's useful here. It depends on the size and shape of kernel you use, but I tried it out with a (5,5) rectangular kernel (instead of the dilatation phase) and it closed some of the gaps :)

Comment: @Soltius exactly!!! That is why I chose it. I tried out the different possibilities as well

Comment: @Jeru can we not take AND operation of the final image from your answer and my input image? That will give us the true characters with grid removed right?

Comment: @SwapnilB.AND operation of my final image with your inverse input image might work. Give it a try

Comment: @JeruLuke is there a way I can talk to you?

Comment: @alexandergs Sure what do you want to talk about?

Comment: @JeruLuke I want to see if you can help me do some stuff and I can pay you by the hours. If so, please send me an email to alexandergs@yahoo.com regards

Comment: @JeruLuke the kink to the kernels is broken, is it anywhere to be found?

Comment: @EzerK Check out [this link](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)

Comment: @JeruLuke, Thanks!!